# webscraping search results in R

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, phantomjs, rvest

I'm new to webscraping and I'm trying to scrape some data that results from a search function within a website. I'm using rvest to pull information and I'm not getting results.  This is the website:

https://www.encompassinsurance.com/agency-locator.aspx#PostalCode=30350&City=&StateProvCd=&Latitude=&Longitude=

This is what I'm running:

```
URL <- 'https://www.encompassinsurance.com/agency-locator.aspx#PostalCode=21403&City=&StateProvCd=&Latitude=&Longitude='

webpage <- read_html(URL)

name_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.locator_result_name')

name_data <- html_text(name_html)
```

When I run this code I get a response of:
character(0)

I would like the response to be the name of each company as a result of the zipcode search (ex. "Townley-Kenton Insurance Agency", "Bradford Turner Insurance Group LLC").

I know there is some Javascript on this page and that I might be missing an important piece but given my limited knowdlge of html, CSS, javascript I'm not sure how to apply V8 or PhantomJS to make this work.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is indeed fetched dynamically using javascript (via an XHR GET request). However, it's possible to send this request directly from R using the `httr` package. It returns a JSON string, which is easy to parse with `jsonlite`.

Pretty much all of the information you would want to scrape will be in the data frame `Info$OfficeInfo`:

```r
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

res <- content(GET(paste0("https://alr.encompassinsurance.com/",
                          "?PostalCode=30350&City=&StateProvCd=",
                          "&Latitude=&Longitude=")), "text")
info <- fromJSON(res)

info$OfficeInfo$Name
#>  [1] "Townley-Kenton Insurance Agency"                          
#>  [2] "Bradford Turner Insurance Group LLC"                      
#>  [3] "Arthur J Gallagher Risk Management Services, Inc."        
#>  [4] "Lanigan Insurance Group Inc"                              
#>  [5] "Haven Insurance Group"                                    
#>  [6] "The Leavitt Insurance Group of Atlanta, Incorporated"     
#>  [7] "Findley Insurance Agency Inc"                             
#>  [8] "Grimes Insurance Agency Inc"                              
#>  [9] "Larry L Talbert Ins Agency DBA Talbert Insurance Services"
#> [10] "The Alliance Group, Inc."                                 
#> [11] "Concierge Insurance Group LLC"                            
#> [12] "Sutter McLellan & Gilbreath Inc"                          
#> [13] "The Wichalonis Insurance Agency"                          
#> [14] "The Beck Agency"                                          
#> [15] "USI Insurance Services LLC"                               
#> [16] "The Insurance Store"                                      
#> [17] "Southern Insurance Associates of Dunwoody"                
#> [18] "D.C.J.D. Corporation DBA The Markey Insurance Group"      
#> [19] "DM Services, Incorporated"                                
#> [20] "Southern Insurance Advisors"                              
#> [21] "Metro Brokers Insurance Services"                         
#> [22] "1 Source Insurance, LLC"                                  
#> [23] "The Bates Agency II, LLC"                                 
#> [24] "Risk & Insurance Consultants Inc"                         
#> [25] "Integrity Insurance & Financial Services Inc"             
#> [26] "HN Insurance Services Inc"                                
#> [27] "Norton Metro LLC"                                         
#> [28] "The Nsure Network LLC"                                    
#> [29] "Henssler Norton Insurance LLC"                            
#> [30] "Brown & Brown Insurance of Georgia"                       
#> [31] "America Insurance Brokers, Inc. DBA AIB"                  
#> [32] "Clear View Insurance Agency"                              
#> [33] "Relation Insurance Services"                              
#> [34] "Partners Risk Services LLC"                               
#> [35] "PointeNorth Insurance Group LLC"                          
#> [36] "Advanced Insurors Inc"                                    
#> [37] "Mcever & Tribble, Inc."                                   
#> [38] "The Bethea Insurance Group, LLC"                          
#> [39] "Watchko - Young Ins Agcy Inc"                             
#> [40] "Sterling Seacrest Partners Inc"                           
#> [41] "Little & Smith, Incorporated"                             
#> [42] "LMG Insurance Services Inc"                               
#> [43] "Granite Risk Advisors LLC"                                
#> [44] "Mountain Lakes Insurance, LLC"                            
#> [45] "Hutchinson Traylor Insurance"                             
#> [46] "Edgewood Partners Insurance Center"                       
#> [47] "ADC Agency"                                               
#> [48] "MLG Insurance & Financial Services"                       
#> [49] "Burnette Insurance Agency"                                
#> [50] "Campbell and Company Enterprise, Incorporated"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>